# Android mobile browser images are pixelated until refresh

Tags: android, image, mobile, browser, rendering

I am currently working on a mobile site, on it I have a group of images marked up as so:

```
<a href="/link/"><img alt="image" src="/assets/image.jpg" /> Link</a>
```

When I initially visit the site from Android (multiple devices) these images load but are rendered grainy and pixelated. However, once I refresh the page on my device the images will then re-load and display crisp as intended. I have only tested this once on iPhone but it looked okay on the first load, so I believe this is Android specific.

I tried setting these as background images via CSS instead of placing them through HTML, I also tried placing an inline style directly on the image declaring the dimensions. With both approaches the problem remained exactly the same.

Each one is around 3kb each and there are 9 of them, the rest of the site is not very heavy and these images are really the only content on this page. I am convinced there must be a limit or constraint that Android puts in place to make pages load faster, but if that is the case is there a way to get around it?

Unfortunately I can not post screenshots or a URL.

Thanks in advance!