# Pixelated/Grainy background images on Android Droid X

Tags: android, css, background-image, meta-tags, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm running into the following issue on my Droid X device w/ 2.3.4 (I have yet to see the problem on other mobile devices). Please see attached screenshots.

You can see from the first screenshot that the background appears to be thatched/pixelated, possibly stretched somehow. The second screenshot is how the background is supposed to appear.

The confusing part to me is that the thatched appearance is only present when I first browse to the page or browse to other pages via links. However, if I refresh my current page via the refresh button, the background then displays correctly as the clean striped appearance in the second image.

I'm using device meta viewport tags to set the initial scale to 1.

Another user asked a similar question here: [Android mobile browser images are pixelated until refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905806/android-mobile-browser-images-are-pixelated-until-refresh) but their particular issue is a bit different than mine, because they are claiming that all of the images are pixelated/grainy. However only the body background on my project appear that way.

[image: Invalid background repeat]
[image: Valid background repeat]

Comment: What are the dimensions of the background image?

Comment: the dimensions are 15x15